# Printing a list of people's names, which each person's name is itself a list of names

Tags: python

So basically, when we enter a list such as

```
[['Bilbo', 'Baggins'], ['Gollum'], ['Tom', 'Bombadil'], ['Aragorn']]
```

into the function, it should print out the elements in each list in a separate line with a space in between. I can't figure out how to do it when the number of elements in each list is unequal.

I am not allowed to use any for loops either

Here is my code:

```
def print_names2(people):
"""Print a list of people's names, which each person's name
   is itself a list of names (first name, second name etc)
"""
    i = 0
    while i < len(people):
        names = list(people[i])
        j = 0
        while j < len(names):
            i += 1
            name = names[j]
            print(name, end=" ")
            j += 1
print_names2([['Bilbo', 'Baggins'], ['Gollum'], ['Tom', 'Bombadil'], 
['Aragorn']])
```

The expected outcome:

```
Bilbo Baggins 
Gollum 
Tom Bombadil 
Aragorn
```

Actual outcome:

```
Bilbo Baggins Tom Bombadil
```

What changes should I do to my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to print an empty line at the end of your initial while loop.

```
def print_names2(people):
"""Print a list of people's names, which each person's name
   is itself a list of names (first name, second name etc)
"""
    i = 0
    while i < len(people):
        names = list(people[i])
        j = 0
        while j < len(names):
            i += 1
            name = names[j]
            print(name, end=" ")
            j += 1
        print("")    

print_names2([['Bilbo', 'Baggins'], ['Gollum'], ['Tom', 'Bombadil'], 
['Aragorn']])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a simpler method.

```
def print_names(people):
    for i in people:
        print (' '.join(i))

people=[['Bilbo', 'Baggins'], ['Gollum'], ['Tom', 'Bombadil'], ['Aragorn']]
print_names(people)
```

Output

```
Bilbo Baggins
Gollum
Tom Bombadil
Aragorn
```

---

Without using a `for` loop.

```
def print_names(people):
    i = 0
    while i < len(people):
        print(' '.join(people[i]))
        i += 1

people=[['Bilbo', 'Baggins'], ['Gollum'], ['Tom', 'Bombadil'], ['Aragorn']]
print_names(people)
```

Comment: OP said, can not use any for loop, for some reason.. You may want to change to while loop.. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯